# z-index not working with elements whose parents are in fixed position

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a web app, with upper and lower elements (`div`), both of them have `position: fixed`.
Each one of these elements has child elements (popups) which also have `position: fixed`.

I want to place the popup above to parent elements. However since I'm using `position: fixed`, the `z-index` property isn't working, because it's inherited from the parents.

I saw that similar question was asked in Stack-overflow, however none of them provide solution to this issue.

See the html/css at: https://jsfiddle.net/pLsdspon/

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="height: 100%;">

  <div style="
        background-color: red;
     position: fixed;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50%;
     top: 0%;   
     z-index: 2; ">
Top
    <div style="   
      background-color: pink;
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
      width: 80px;
      height: 200px;
      top: 40%;
      left: 100px;
      z-index: 20; ">
      PopUp-Top - Need to be on top!
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="
     background-color: green;
     position: fixed;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     z-index: 2; ">
Bottom
    <div style="  
      background-color: lightgreen;
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
      width: 80px;
      height: 200px;
      top: 40%;
      left: 200px;
      z-index: 20; ">
      PopUp-Bottom - Need to be on top!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the meanwhile change *`z-index: 1`* for your green div.

Comment: # vivekkupadhya - setting the green element z-index to be 1, wan't solve this issue, then the 2nd popup will be under

Comment: z-index will only work with siblings so as your popups are not on the same level, they will be defined by their parents z-index when it comes to overlapping the header or the footer.  If it is a popup (ie you are using some sort of js to make it show / hide), then you will need to change the z-index of the parent at the same time you make the popup show

Comment: Why do you want/need nested fixed divs?

Comment: #Huelfe - The green and the red divs are the parent of all the rest of the elements (content and footer), therefor they are in fixed position. The pink and the lightgreen divs are popup, therefore the need to be in fixed position, since they are floating on top off all the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is that what I'm trying to do is simply impassible.

The answer by *#Krypton* indeed solve this issue by altering the html, however in my situation altering the html order isn't possible.

The order of elements is called the **Stacking Order**, the stacking order is: 
1. If no z-index or position then the stacking order is as the html markup order. 
2. All positioned elements (`relative`, `absolute` and `fixed`) appear on top of all none positioned elements (`static`). 
3. z-index works only on positioned elements, and it will create Stacking Context.

**Stacking Context** 
Group of elements with common parent create **Stacking Context** if one of the next conditions are meet: 
1. The root document element (the `<html>` element). 
2. Positioned element with z-index 
3. Element with opacity less the 1 *(this isn't known by most of web developers)* 
All the elements in **Stacking Context** move together in the stacking order, 
meaning that if element `a` inside staking context `A`, **can't** be above element `b` inside staking context `B`, if the stacking order of `B` is higher the `A`,
even if the element 'a' has z-index of a million.

**Update**: new css roles that create Stacking context: `transform`, `filter`, `css-region` and `pages_media`.

**The order inside the Stacking Context:** 
1. root element 
2. positioned element with negative z-index. 
3. none positioned elements in the order of the html markup 
4. positioned elements 
5. positioned elements with z-index according to the z-index.

- Now back to the question, in this example both the red and the green div create stacking context since they are positioned (fixed) and have z-index.
- Both of them have the same z-index (value of 2), therefor there stacking order is the red below the green since this is the order of the html markup.
- Now lets look at the pink and the lightgreen elements, the pink is nested inside the red elements and the lightgreen inside the green elements,
  since the red element has lower staking order than the green, all the nested elements inside the red elements appear below all the elements inside the green elements.

To fix this issue we need to create a new element that will create a new stacking context with higher stacking order than the red and the green div and place our popups inside of that elements.

Reference: *What No One Told You About Z-Index* by **Philip Walton**:
https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Did you read the alternative solution below the code in my answer? Wrapping the div's in an entirely new div will allow you to use the `z-index` the way you would like ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` isn't working the way you would like because you're nesting a div within a div not because you have the position set to fixed.
Why not just place the popup `div`'s outside(ontop) of the others?
https://jsfiddle.net/7efx38um/1/

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="height: 100%;">

 <div style="
   background-color: red;
   position: fixed;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50%;
   top: 0%;   
   z-index: 1;
   ">
   Top
 </div>
  <div style="   
   background-color: pink;
   position: fixed;
   display: block;
   width: 80px;
   height: 200px;
   top: 40%;
   left: 100px;
   z-index: 20;
   ">
   PopUp-Top - Need to be on top!
  </div>
  

 
 <div style="
   background-color: green;
   position: fixed;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   z-index: 1;
   ">
   Bottom
    </div>
  <div style="  
   background-color: lightgreen;
   position: fixed;
   display: block;
   width: 80px;
   height: 200px;
   top: 40%;
   left: 200px;
   z-index: 20;
   ">
   PopUp-Bottom - Need to be on top!
  </div>

 

</body>
</html>
```

Also alternatively if you'd like both the banner and popup `div`'s inside one another you could create dummy `div`'s around both, that way the popups won't use the same style as the banners ;)

'

Comment: #Krypton - "The z-index isn't working not because you have the position set to fixed but because you're nesting a div within a div" - this line is wrong. z-index works inside nested div, but when using position fixed, all child elements inherited  the z-index of the base elements (positioned 'fixed')

Comment: What you're saying about the `z-index` is correct however, the problem is the div nested in another div not the position fixed... If you need to use position fixed while keeping the `z-index` global than you can't nest the div's together, it's as simple as that, Jack. The problem is the div's if position fixed is required! 
And by "isn't working" I don't mean that the z-index isn't functioning at all I mean that it's not working the way you'd like. Edited my answer if that wasn't clear.. Two people have said the same things to you, it might be wise to listen.